# How would I reference an image in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, reference, firebase-storage

How would I go about referencing an image in firebase storage? I'm trying to embed it into my html in an img tag. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically use a so-called download URL for that. From the [Firebase documentation on getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url):

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  // This can be inserted into an <img> tag
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', url);
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```